# How to compare variables with filtering blank values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have five fields with respective values:

```
var valOne = document.getElementById("one").value;
var valTwo = document.getElementById("two").value;
var valThree = document.getElementById("three").value;
var valFour = document.getElementById("four").value;
var valFive = document.getElementById("five").value;
```

Now if I want to set a condition only for filled values, like if `valOne` and `valTwo` are not blank while others are blank, then:

```
if(valOne == "1" && valTwo == "2")
{
   alert("match found");
}
```

Same if `valOne` and `valThree` and `valFour` are not blank while the other two are blank, then:

```
if(valOne == "1" && valThree == "2" && valFour == "4")
{
   alert("match found");
}
```

Please note that if `valOne` is not blank, then only 1 value will appear to compare with its given value.

Meaning 1,2,3,4,5 is fixed for `valOne`,`valTwo`,`valThree`,`valFour`,`valFive`.

I am good in JavaScript, so a simple clue would really be helpful for me.

Comment: How about `valOne != ""` ? If you are _good in JavaScript_ then what is stopping you achieving this ?

Comment: Hello @RayonDabre actually, i have tried that all thing already but it will allow me to fire if condition only if the valOne is not blank if valOne is blank then other filled values will not execute.

Comment: Provided code is not enough to guess things...Kindly provide JSFiddle...

Comment: Refer this if it makes sense...https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9eguejd0/

Comment: Hey, @RayonDabre I have checked that fiddle but don't you think this will be long if condition for every different blank and filled values ?

Comment: For random conditions, I don't think there is any other way around...

Comment: Please look this jsfiddle i have tried before https://jsfiddle.net/KirankumarDafda/swo6f1rh/

Comment: Well in this case..Go with the solution provided below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use a method like this

```
function isValid( idArray, validValueArray )
{
   for( var counter = 0; counter < idArray.length; counter++)
   {
      var elem = document.getElementById( idArray[ counter ] );
      var value = elem ? elem.value : "";
      if ( value && value.length > 0 && value != validValueArray[ counter ]  )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}

isValid( [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ], [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ] );
```

Or you can pass the ids and values in terms of key and value

```
var keyValues = {
   "one" : "1",
   "two" : "2",
   "three" : "3",
   "four" : "4"
}
isValid( keyValues );
function isValid( keyValues )
{
   for( var id in keyValues )
   {
      var elem = document.getElementById( id );
      var value = elem ? elem.value : "";
      if ( value && value.length > 0 && value != keyValues [ id]  )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: `{}` would make more sense..`Key => Value...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @gurvinder372, i will try this and let you know if this is working for me or not :)

Comment: I have completed this, with some other changes, which fulfill my requirements. Thanks again